# TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/profile/

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I got an error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/profile/
<ExtendsNode: extends "registration/accounts/base.html"> must be the first tag in the template
```

I wrote `base.html`:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% load staticfiles 'bootflat/css/bootflat.min.css' %}">
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <p class="navbar-text">HELLO</p>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <p class="navbar-text">{{  user.get_username }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`profile.html` is:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% extends "registration/accounts/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <html lang="ja">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootflat/css/bootflat.min.css' %}">
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

　　<a href="{% url 'kenshinresults'%}">SEE YOUR PHOTO</a>

    <div class="container">
      <form action="{% url 'accounts:upload_save' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>SEND PHOTO</p>
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ p_id }}" name="p_id">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>

{% endblock %}
```

I found only `base.html`  was showed accurately, but when I tried `base.html` inherit `profile.html`,this error happens. Before,these 2 files are loaded  accurately, but when I added `href="{% static 'bootflat/css/bootflat.min.css' %}"` to `profile.html`,this error happpens. Why does such an error happen? How can I fix this? I think adding {% load staticfiles %} is right to profile.html,but is it wrong?

Comment: Can you add to your question the full backtrace error that you are receiving?

Comment: What are you not understanding? The error message is totally explicit. Extends must be the first tag in profile.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that you must write `extends` tag first in your template.
You can read more about this in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance)

So, you should write `{% extends "registration/accounts/base.html" %}` first in `profile.html`

```
{% extends "registration/accounts/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
  ...
{% endblock %}
```

After that all will works fine!

Answer (score 3):

You should consider your `base.html` file as a layout and your `profile.html` as a template file rendered inside this layout.

For this reason:

- `load staticfiles` block should be inserted in `base.html` and should be insert in every file where you are loading static assets (see next bullet point)
- when you refer to static assets inside `src=` is enough to load it with `static` path helper
- `profile.html` should extend the layout `base.html` and whatever is included in the `{% block content %}` will be rendered inside the block content tag in your body

*base.html*

```
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootflat/css/bootflat.min.css' %}">
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  {% block content %} 
  <!-- your body is fine -->
  {% end block %}
  </body>
</html>
```

*profile.html*

```
{% extends "registration/accounts/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <a href="{% url 'kenshinresults'%}">SEE YOUR PHOTO</a>
    <form action="{% url 'accounts:upload_save' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>SEND PHOTO</p>
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ p_id }}" name="p_id">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>  
{% endblock %}
```

**Edit**
as remarked by Daniel Roseman

Comment: Your comment is a bit misleading. Normally you *do* need to load template tags in each child template; the reason you wouldn't do so here is because there is no need for all that HTML in that child template anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Would you like to edit my answer? Otherwise i would edit it accordlying.